# Get an element and its CSS attribute in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have products which i can view in a table.
Every product is on a different row.
If a product is expired the color of the text in the row will be red.
I need to check using SeleniumIDE the color of the text.
I already tried verifyAttribute and a javascript but i keep getting an error.

So does any one have any solution to this problem in Selenium IDE

This is Xpath to a row of an expired product

```
"//table[@id='maintable']/tbody/tr[@id='2']"
```

all text in the td inside this tr is red.

Any solution ?

Comment: Always give example input matching the XPath you provided.

Comment: @JensErat i have 2 rows, 1 showing text in black the other showing text in red, the xpath is for the second row, how can i check it using selenium?

Comment: Just put some HTML snippet in the question (use the "edit" button, don't put it in the comments; and make sure to format it as code, so it shows up). Everything else just leads to wild guessing and horribly long discussions in comments.